# WordPress generated files edited with HTML

Tags: html, css, wordpress, deployment, localhost

After basic knowledge of HTML/CSS/JS and Jquery, I got myself into WordPress. In order to save time and not build things from zero, I would use pre-made templates, and modify them according to the built of the desired future webpage. There might be a huge misconception in my head, but so far I havent found reply for this solution.

I have a locally running WordPress webpage with the help of WAMP. My webpage would consist 3 separate HTML files, lets say "index.html, contact.html, about.html". My issue is that after generating those pages in WordPress, I dont find any way to modify the HTML file of those sites. Nor locally in my computer, nor in the surface of WordPress. I found the "editor" function in WP, but apparently it lets me to edit only the CSS file.

My main goal is to generate the file with a template, than import it to BRACKETS / ATOM / etc and custom-shape the HTML and CSS on it. What am I missing ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress only has templates it uses according to the type of content (page, blog post or any other custom post type you define in the theme) requested. All your actual data is stored in the `mysql` database. This data is retrieved and inserted into the template and then the generated file is sent to the client. So, you wont find any `.html` files in the wordpress core. 
My suggestion is to view the source in the browser, copy, paste and edit in your favourite editor.

Comment: thanks. What I am exactly looking for is to have an acces and alter the "generated file?"

Comment: Is it access to the template files you want? If that is the case, you can access those files from the 'editor' in 'Appearance'(Appearance > Editor). Wordpress has something called 'template hierarchy'. When it receives a request, it uses this hierarchy to determine which template file to use to serve this request. You can find more information about it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview). Also note that not all themes play by wordpress' rules and load their own templates. If you are using such a theme, then look for theme documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using HTML files as a template which are not dynamically converted into wordpress theme. that's why you can't edit these files. You need to follow these steps.
1. your index file must be in index.php not index.html
2. style.css file with valid codes and most important thing is you need to know wordpress theme development. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/ This will help you